# Regex empty string or number

Tags: angularjs, regex, angular, ng-pattern

Here is my `ng-pattern= "/^[0-9]+(.[0-9][0-9])?$/i"` which will allow only any digits and decimal followed by 2 digits, but I want it to match empty string too.

How can I do it?

Comment: Use `^(?:pattern)?$`. Note you need to escape `.` to match a literal `.`

Comment: A quick change you could make to that regex is swap + for * `"/^[0-9]*(.[0-9][0-9])?$/i"`